# Why is there no vertical space inserted between these two divs?

Tags: html, css

In the following code I would expect to see 15px of vertical space between div a and div b.  Why do I not see any space? Edit: Many people are not answering the question.  I don't want to get something working, I want an explanation for the behavior I see.

```
<div class="a"> 
  <span> lkjjj </span>
</div>

<div class="b"> 
  <span> lkj lkjl kjlj l  </span>
</div>



.a { width: 50px; border: 1px solid gray; float: left; }

.b { 
  margin: 15px 0 0 0; 
  clear: both; 
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid gray; 
 }
```

​Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate.

http://jsfiddle.net/nUNM6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nUNM6/4/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have floating and margin-collapse

Here are three examples next to each other
http://jsfiddle.net/nUNM6/6/

Inspect carefully the margin of `.b` in Firefox Firebug or Chrome Element-Inspector

---

edit
changed something in jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

On `.a`, you have declared `float:left`. That will cause it to flow over .b's margin. http://jsfiddle.net/nUNM6/1/

Answer (score 1):

There is no space because you're using `float:left` on "a".

Answer (score 0):

The `a` block is floating, which causes it to count as white space when `b`'s margin is calculated. If you put the margin on the bottom of `a` instead it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the `float:left` and your margin will work

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this code between the two divs, a & b:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

with this CSS:

.clear {clear: both;}

This will get your gap to show in between.